# DB2 zOS: XMLQUERY with long namespace and narrow editor

Tags: sql, db2, zos

This sounds like a stuipd questions nowadays. Unfortunately some of use still have to cope with technology from last millennial.

How can I use `XMLQUERY` with `declare namespace` and a namespace like `urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100` with an editor that is only 70 characters wide?

Basically I would like to run:

```sql
SELECT
    xmlcast(
    XMLQUERY('declare namespace ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100";
            $e//ram:GrandTotalAmount'
            PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT xmlcol) AS "e"
    ) AS integer)
FROM
    mytable
```

But the namespace declaration is too long for the editor which only is 70 characters wide.

So far I found no way to break the declaration into multiple lines using `' || <newline> '` but any concat results in `SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD PASSING`

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, leave out the namespace and use `$e//*:GrandTotalAmount`

Comment: I find it funny to read "an editor which is 70 characters wide". Since you've added the `zos` tag I assume you're talking aboit the ISPF editor, which by no means is "only 70 characters wide". With the correct settings the ISPF screen can be up to 160 characters wide, but even this does not limit the maximum line length you can edit. So, what is the environment you are working with, exactly. ow do you experience that "70 charater limit". If you provide more details, I might be able to help.

Comment: If it is ISPF Editor, it is not limited to 70 bytes, but the **file** being edited is probably **80 byte FB** which might limit you to 8 byte line number + 72 byte of data.

Comment: As a side note: What exactly do you mean by "technology from last millenium"? PCs? Linux? The Internet? Mainframes?

Comment: @BruceMartin You are right. It's actually seems to be a file with limited width where I have to put the SQL. The file acutally also seems to be wider, but it doesn't get read in full with if I enter more than 70-something characters.

Comment: If you use the **right pf** keys (or enter right in the command line) you may see more alternatively enter **num off** in the command line and then right

Comment: @BruceMartin The behaviour described by MarcusFey seems to be consistent with DSNTEP2's documentation: "Input data set. In this data set, you can enter any number of SQL statements, each terminated with a semicolon. A statement can span multiple lines, but DSNTEP2 or DSNTEP4 reads only the first 72 bytes of each line. You must explicitly commit any SQL statements except the last one." - so there seems to be no way to use longer records.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the program you use to execute these statements. With the standard DSNTEP2/SPUFI you just code up to column 72 and continue in column 1 like this (note that the column-numbering line is not part of the file, it's just the one displayed by using `COLS`):

```
//SYSTSIN  DD *                                                         
  DSN SYSTEM(DB2T)                                                      
   RUN PROGRAM(DSNTEP2)    -                                            
       PLAN   (DSNTEP2)                                                 
  END                                                                   
//*                                                                     
//SYSIN    DD *                                                         
----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7--
   SELECT * FROM SOMEDATA.PLAN_TABLE WHERE EXPLAIN_TIME BETWEEN '2019-12
-13-00.00.00.000000' AND '2019-12-15-00.00.00.000000'                   
   FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY;                
/*
```

I thought that concatenating the query-expression should have worked, but it seems like IBM doesn't allow expressions in this place.
I managed to break up my query-expression in certain places by changing to a new line within the quotes (like after a `/` in the path), but not in others. If you can#t find such places (by experimenting), you will have to resort to the "column 72 -> column 1" tactic above.

Comment: I think expression are not allowed here, [doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=functions-xmlquery) names it xquery-expression-*constant* (DB2LUW doesn't allow `||` here, just tried, got SQLCODE=-104)

Comment: @nfgl thanks for the hint. It really seems like you can't use expressions here. Too bad :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for @data_henrik's comment. It was really that simple:

```sql
SELECT
    xmlcast(
    XMLQUERY('$e//*:GrandTotalAmount'
            PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT xmlcol) AS "e"
    ) AS integer)
FROM
    mytable
```

That great because there are half a dozen namespaces in the XML file I would actually have to `declare` to get all the other elements/attributes iI need.